# Import class into ionic 3 and error when instantiating class

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to ionic 3 and I'm trying to register. I have a accounts screen called accounts.ts that gets in `src/pages/accounts/accounts.ts` and then I'm trying to create a class where DAO will be referring to that class, I created it in the following `src/dao/dao-accounts.ts` location.

Some errors are showing up

My first doubt is this, do you mind this current?

```
import {DAOContas} from '../../dao/da-contacts';
```

I am also wanting to return a list of data but an error appears like this
:

> uncaught (im promisse): referrererror: value is not defined
>   referenceerror: value is not defined at new ContasPage

class **dao-accounts.ts**

```
export class DAOContas {

  constructor()
  {
    this.list = [];
  }

  getList()
  {
    this.list = [
    {descricao:"Alimentação"},
    {descricao:"Lazer"},
    {descricao:"Transporte"}
    ];

    return this.list;
  }

}
```

method **ContasPage.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DAOContas } from '../../dao/dao-contas';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'contas.html'
})
export class ContasPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      this.dao = new DAOContas();
      this.listcontas = this.dao.getList();
  }

}
```

Error Occurs When Instantiating DAOContas

Comment: Hey Bruno, you should share full min repro code if you want ot get some help. Your question right now contains tons of typo errors and also is not clear enough

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the rest of the code ... if you can help me, the problem is when I perform the following command this.dao = new DAOContas ();

Comment: So what does DAOContas do for you? it acts as provider of data right?

Comment: You need to share FULL classes not just parts of it as in your question right now it is unclear what are you import statements in the daoContas class etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue here relates to dependency injection pattern. See [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern) of how that works for more info.

Based on the code you provided it seems like the issue is with the way you organized your code and declared (or did not declare) certain variables.

In your ContasPage do ensure you:

- import the class
- declare the vars
- do assignments in the constructor

So in your case you didn't declare the vars before the constructor:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DAOContas } from '../../dao/dao-contas';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'contas.html'
})
export class ContasPage {

  // declare your vars here:
  dao: any;
  listcontas: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController
  ) {
    this.dao = new DAOContas();
    this.listcontas = this.dao.getList();
  }

}
```

Same thing in your class you forgot to declare the var list:

```
export class DAOContas {

    list: Array<{ descricao: string }>

    constructor() {
        this.list = [];
    }

    getList() {
        this.list = [
            { descricao: "Alimentação" },
            { descricao: "Lazer" },
            { descricao: "Transporte" }
        ];

        return this.list;
    }

}
```

Also since your DAOContas to me looks like a data provider, I would probably think about turning it into a provider and injecting it into your page via constructor:

Make sure DAOContas is injectable:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class DAOContas {

    list: Array<{ descricao: string }>

    constructor() {
        this.list = [];
    }

    getList() {
        this.list = [
            { descricao: "Alimentação" },
            { descricao: "Lazer" },
            { descricao: "Transporte" }
        ];

        return this.list;
    }

}
```

Add it to your app.module.ts as provider:

```
import { DAOContas } from '../../src/providers/dao-contacts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    bla
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    DAOContas,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    TestProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally inject it to your page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DAOContas } from '../../providers/dao-contacts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage2 {

  listcontas: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public dao: DAOContas
  ) {
    this.listcontas = this.dao.getList();
    console.log(this.listcontas)
  }

}
```